# Generating Unique Values for MySQL Unique Fields

Tags: php, mysql, unique

When a user signs up to my website, for example, I create a unique string of length 40 and insert it into the database. We then send an email to the newly signed up user containing this unique string in the form of an URL, and this all works fine.
But how do you create and insert this signup entity ensuring that the field with the unique property is actually unique?

My current approach is as follows:

```
$key = '';
$repeat = true;
while ($repeat) {
    $key = generate_hash(40);
    $is_unique = (count($model->get_by_key($key)) === 0) ? true : false;
    $repeat = ($is_unique) ? false : true;
}
// At this point I know the key is unique and can insert it...
```

I am not happy with this code, as I try to avoid while loops in general. Is there a better way to achieve what I am doing here?

The bottom line is that the MySQL field containing these keys has the unique property and I need to know that no unique-violations will occur when inserting these keys.

Comment: Have a look at [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

Comment: Does this string have to be (globally) unique? Or do you want the nonce (very) hard to be guessed? Since you mentioned [new user,signup,email] my guess is: the latter.

Comment: These keys should be unique. The signed up user clicks on the link containing this key in his email and the key is used to determine which user account to unlock. This is just one example of where unique keys are used and there has to be a better way of generating them

Comment: In the example you've described the nonce doesn't have to be globally unique - just hard to be guessed.  `please confirm your email account by following the link: http://.....?userid=<thisneedstobeunique>&nonce=<thisonlyhastobehardtoguess>`, just like debit cards and atm machines: There isn't only one card with a specific pin, but having a specific card (id) its hard (enough) to guess the corresponding pin.

Comment: Ok, so the keys dont need to be unique here. And I should ensure that the presented nonce & userid match in the db before unlocking the user account. This approach is definitely better - thanks!

Comment: correct. random/hard-to-guess + unique: hard problem; hard-to-guess+something-unique-but-not-secret: eas...ier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, basically you have two approaches.

1. Let the DB handle this and use **UUID()** to create a unique identifier that you can use in the emails.

   According to your MySQL version you have some options:

   **A.** With **MySQL 4.1** and above you can use the function directly with INSERT INTO:

   ```
   INSERT INTO table_name 
       (unique_id, field1, field2) 
   VALUES 
       (UUID(), "smth", "smth")
   ```

   **B.** With **MySQL 5.0** you can create a TRIGGER and have the unique field automatically filled upon insertion:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER 
   unique_id
   BEFORE INSERT ON 
   table_name 
   FOR EACH ROW
   SET NEW.unique_id = UUID()
   ```
2. You can check programatically if the the generated id is really unique. The same you are doing now but you can refactor the code a little bit like so:

   ```
   $key = generate_hash(40);
   while ( count($model->get_by_key($key)) ) {
       $key = generate_hash(40);
   }

   //here you have an unique id in $key
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are built in unique id functions in almost every language for that.In php,

```
echo uniqid();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate 256^40 different 40-characters strings.
Sun will explode before you generate 2 identical strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `md5(time())` as your unique value instead. `md5` of `time` wouldn't be same for each user submitting.

```
$time = time();
$md5 = md5($time);
```

As long as `md5()` just containing 32 string length, you can add an unique word after the `md5()`.

```
$unique = $md5."uniq1234";
```

Now you have 40 unique string length. At last you can add `$unique` as your unique value in database

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to generate uniqueID ,

```
function keygen($length=10)
{
    $key = '';
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    mt_srand((float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000));

    $inputs = array_merge(range('z','a'),range(0,9),range('A','Z'));

    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
    {
        $key .= $inputs{mt_rand(0,61)};
    }
    return $key;
}

echo keygen(10);
```